# Creating referenced table element

Tags: c, lua

I created a more or less complex table in C. Now I want to create a reference on a lower level of the tree. Is this possible?

Idea:

```
ELEM000 +--> ELEM010
        +--> ELEM020 +--> ELEM120
        |            +--> **ELEM121**
        |            +--> ELEM122
        +--> ELEM030 +--> ELEM130
        |            +--> ELEM131
        |            +--> ELEM132
        +--> **ELEM121**
```

The ELEM121 should also be visible one level above, i.e. be a reference

I added an example of what I wanted to to..

```
void PushL(lua_State *L, const char * str) {
char s[255];
strcpy(s, "ELEM"); strcat(s, str);   lua_pushstring(L, s);  // key
strcpy(s, "Value"); strcat(s, str);  lua_pushstring(L, s);  // value
lua_settable(L, -3);
}
void MakeTable( lua_State *L )
{
lua_pushstring(L, "TBL0");  // name of sub-table

lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);
lua_checkstack(L, 3);
{

PushL(L, "000");

lua_pushstring(L, "TBL1");

lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);
lua_checkstack(L, 3);
{
  PushL(L, "010");
  PushL(L, "020");

  lua_pushstring(L, "TBL2");

  lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);
  lua_checkstack(L, 3);
  {
    PushL(L, "120");
    PushL(L, "121");
    PushL(L, "122");
    lua_settable(L, -3);
  }
  PushL(L, "030");

  lua_pushstring(L, "TBL3");

  lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);
  lua_checkstack(L, 3);
  {
    PushL(L, "130");
    PushL(L, "131");
    PushL(L, "132");
    lua_settable(L, -3);
  }

  lua_settable(L, -3);
}

lua_pushstring(L, "ELEM121");
lua_pushstring(L, "SHOULD BE A REFERENCE TO ELEM121");
lua_settable(L, -3);
}
lua_setglobal(L,"____myTable");
}
```

Comment: Create the table and insert it into both other tables.

Comment: Could you show your code doing this, so that I won't suggest something completely different.

Comment: The answer completely depends on how you implemented this complex table.

Comment: Please show client code. Do you mean to change the value in either place and have the change reflected on both places? (That would be the hardest case.) Or, something simpler?

Comment: code is updated in my question. And yes, wanting a "reference" means any change should be updated in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line: In Lua, field variables cannot be referenced but there are ways of doing what you want.

Here is a comparison between C data structures and Lua data structures.

In C, you either:

1. have a copy of the value in two places

   You can create copies in Lua, too.
2. or, have a pointer in one place that points to the other place.

   In C, that means you'd have to access them differently, one with a pointer deference, the other without.

   In Lua, you could have a function in one place that returns the value in the other place. That means you'd have to access them differently, one with a function call, the other without.

The following is equivalent to a read-only pointer:

```
local ELEM000 = { 
  ELEM010 = "ELEM010 value",
  ELEM020 = { 
    ELEM120 = "ELEM120 value",
    ELEM121 = "ELEM121 value",
    ELEM122 = "ELEM122 value" },
  ELEM030 = { 
    ELEM130 = "ELEM130 value",
    ELEM131 = "ELEM131 value",
    ELEM132 = "ELEM132 value" },
  ELEM121 = function(self) return self.ELEM020.ELEM121 end }

print(ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121)
print(ELEM000:ELEM121())
ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121 = ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121 .. " updated" 
print(ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121)
print(ELEM000:ELEM121())
```

If you need a writable pointer then another approach would be needed.

---

#### Update

A simple way for a writable pointer is to add an optional value parameter. This is commonly used in JavaScript APIs but JavaScript has the advantage of the `undefined` data type. In Lua, we'll have to use `nil`, which means that you can't write `nil` as a value.

```
ELEM121 = function(self, value) 
    if (value ~= nil) then self.ELEM020.ELEM121 = value end 
    return self.ELEM020.ELEM121 
    end
```

---

For true read-write field access, use the __index and __newindex metatmethods. This requires that the field actually not have a key in the table. The metamethods are invoked when indexing a non-existing field for reading (__index) or for writing (__newindex).

```
local ELEM000 = { 
  ELEM010 = "ELEM010 value",
  ELEM020 = { 
    ELEM120 = "ELEM120 value",
    ELEM121 = "ELEM121 value", -- captured as the initial value
    ELEM122 = "ELEM122 value"}, 
  ELEM030 = { 
    ELEM130 = "ELEM130 value",
    ELEM131 = "ELEM131 value",
    ELEM132 = "ELEM132 value" },
  ELEM121 = nil -- ignored 
}

setmetatable(ELEM000, { 
  __index = function(base, key) 
      if (key=="ELEM121") then return base.ELEM020.ELEM121 
      else return nil end end,
  __newindex = function (base, key, value) 
      if (key=="ELEM121") then base.ELEM020.ELEM121 = value 
      else rawset(base, key, value) end end })

setmetatable(ELEM000.ELEM020, { 
  ELEM121 = ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121, --[[ backing storage for field, 
                                          initialized to existing value]] 
  __index = function(base, key) 
      if (key=="ELEM121") then return getmetatable(base).ELEM121 
      else return nil end end,
  __newindex = function (base, key, value) 
      if (key=="ELEM121") then getmetatable(base).ELEM121 = value 
      else rawset(base, key, value) end end })

-- make sure metamethods will be invoked on these fields  
rawset(ELEM000, "ELEM121", nil)     
rawset(ELEM000.ELEM020, "ELEM121", nil)
```

Usage:

```
print(ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121)
print(ELEM000.ELEM121)

ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121 = ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121 .. " updated" 
print(ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121)
print(ELEM000.ELEM121)

ELEM000.ELEM121 = ELEM000.ELEM121 .. " again" 
print(ELEM000.ELEM020.ELEM121)
print(ELEM000.ELEM121)
```

There various places to store the backing field and different styles of coding the metamethods. This code is perhaps too concise. And, I leave it to you to code it in Lua C API, if you wish.

Comment: Case 1 covers putting a reference to the same table in both places. (A value is a reference or a primitive.) He didn't say if the ELEM121 value was a table or not. Case 2 is an answer for a read-only reference to a field. I'll leave it for the question asker to clarify what he needs.

Comment: Fair enough. I was assuming the elements were tables but it doesn't actually say that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sorry I forgot to say: 
a) All elements are table entries (nested tables)
b) it should create a real reference and not a read-only entry. The user shall either read/write to the original one or to the referenced one without any difference for him.